# Live Statistic Equation

Tags: php, linux, unix, timestamp, equation

So I am calculating an equation so that I can echo out a statistic. This statistic will be bounced back to HTML via ajax and written out to the user. a setInterval will make sure that it gets updated real time. It is very similar to this http://www.usagain.com/ on the left hand side. The problem is I want to start this incrementation at a certain number.

I'm basing it off of the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_TIME]` so that it always increments and only ever gets reset once it reaches its max. The problem is I need to define a starting number. Here is the equation that user **Uboonto** came up with:

`value = ( timestamp % ((max_limit - min_limit) / 1.5 ) ) * 1.5 + min_limit`

This will increment ever second by 1.5 - the problem is that this equation starts randomly between `$min` and `$max` instead at a starting number I define. Does anybody know how to modify this equation so I can have a starting number that I can define?

I tried:

`value = ( (timestamp + modifier) % ((max_limit - min_limit) / 1.5 ) ) * 1.5 + min_limit`

and

`value = ( (timestamp - modifier) % ((max_limit - min_limit) / 1.5 ) ) * 1.5 + min_limit`

but no luck. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why not just define it before you overwrite it in a loop, like you're supposed to anyway. `$value = 'default'; while(){ $value = 'whatever'}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I overwrite the value it sill won't start at any number I want it to. It just starts at a middle number between `$min` and `$max`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing to begin with. I assumed value was just a variable that you were augmenting through a loop. You should post more code so we can figure out what's happening.

Comment: I updated my question with more info I guess. It's hard to explain though so feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I agree with @MetalFrog - this question is really vague.  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, so you're updating the value through ajax, and you just want to have a predefined value _before_ the first post and update?

Comment: @MetalFrog have you ran the code above? That equation gives you a number. If you define a min and max and use ajax & setInterval it will add 1.5 every second. The equation above starts at a number between min & max. I want it to start at a number that I define. So I need to edit the equation to start at a predefined number.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee How could I run the code? We have no idea what any of these pseudo-variables are supposed to be... Putting that exact code into a php file would do nothing.

Comment: @MetalFrog It's just a counter like the question says. Those variables are pretty self explanatory. You have a max limit and min limit. Placing numbers inside max limit and min limit would produce a number random number (just like the question says) and it will increment, showing you what I'm talking about in my question. I could understand having confusion on the modifier but no matter what the modifier is the code would still work. You should play around with code more.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee lol, I'll be sure to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to just calculate the difference between some arbitrary point in time and a known value at that time and multiply by the number of increments per second:

```
$startValue = 1000000; // 1 million
$startTime  = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2012); // 2012-01-01 00:00:00
$incPerSec  = 1; // increment $startValue by this for every second elapsed since $startTime
$seconds    = time() - $startTime;

$value = $startValue + ($seconds * $incPerSec);

echo $value;
```

Comment: See then I'm still guessing a date so that the number reflects what I want to incrementer to start at.

Comment: You have to start it somewhere if you want the number to constantly be going up.  Just pick a date.  It doesn't really matter what it is.  Then adjust the `$startValue` as needed.

Comment: I gotcha. So pretty much I want to start the date in advance so it will start counting from that date. Verrry cool.